# Is the limit of a squence of p-adic integer also a p-adic integer?

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Given a squence of p-adic integers $\{x_n\}$, and assume $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n\in\mathbb Q_p$ exists in the sense of p-adic metric. Do we know the limit is also a p-adic integer, i.e. $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n\in\mathbb Z_p$?

I was thinking about decimal expansion of some square root. Say $\sqrt2$ in $\mathbb Z_7$, we can approximate the square root with decimal expansion $3+1\cdot7+2\cdot7^2\cdots$, which gives a sequence of p-adic integers. Then if the limit exists, does it mean $\sqrt2\in\mathbb Z_7$? I am fairly new to p-adic numbers so any help is appreciated!

Comment: How do you define the sequence convergence in the p-adic case? As Cauchy sequence?

Comment: I meant convergence under the p-adic metric. I've just edited the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a closed subset (it is the closed ball of radius $1$).

To answer your second question, this does mean that $\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{Z}_7$. Another way to see this is that $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a PID, hence a UFD, and so integrally closed in its field of fractions $\mathbb{Q}_p$. The equation for $\sqrt{2}$ is $x^2 - 2 \in \mathbb{Z}_p[x]$.

Comment: Thanks! This answers my question. I was just thinking square root 5 being a p-adic "integer" is kinda weird. But you elaboration makes it sound reasonable.

Comment: No problem :) Yes it does, this is just one of many strange things in the padic world!

Comment: That property is not so weird regardless, if you phrase it like this: If an element of $\mathbb Z$ has square roots (or $n$-th roots) in $\mathbb Q$, then those square roots (or $n$-th roots) are already in $\mathbb Z$. And now the same holds for $\mathbb Z_p$ and $\mathbb Q_p$. More generally, if a polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb Z$ has roots in $\mathbb Q$, then those roots are in $\mathbb Z$. Same for the $p$-adic versions. The concept to look up is "integral closure".

Comment: By the way, I'd say, not that "square root of $2$ is a $5$-adic integer", but that there is a $5$-adic integer which is a square root of $2$. Seems like most people find that pedantic, I find it important to grasp the subtle difference. Cf. math.stackexchange.com/a/4007515/96384.

Comment: Funny, looks like this slipped everyone's notice but $\sqrt{2} \not \in \mathbb{Z}_5$. I think originally the poster meant $\mathbb{Z}_7$ as their digit expansion consists of powers of $7$.

Comment: @Merosity wow thanks, yes I didn't check - will edit accordingly